# Why are some hissatsu techniques in Inazuma Eleven never used again?

Tags: inazuma-eleven

I'm not sure whether anyone around has watched and followed Inazuma Eleven enough to be able to answer this... but here goes!

A brief description: Hissatsu techniques are special techniques in the anime which enables the users to do some powerful moves, including goal keeper techniques, defense, offense and shoots.

Now, I noticed that there are some hissatsu techniques which aren't used again, especially those used in the movies of the anime:

- [Maximum fire](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Maximum_Fire) used by [Gouenji Shuuya](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Gouenji) in the movie [Gekijyouban Inazuma Eleven Saikyou Gundan Ogre](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Inazuma_Eleven_the_Movie:_The_Invasion_of_the_Strongest_Army_Ogre) hasn't been used anywhere else in the anime.
- [Omega the Hand](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Omega_The_Hand) used by [Endou Mamoru](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Endou_Mamoru) in the same movie never appeared again. Ironically enough, the episodes immediately following it have Endou looking for a stronger hissatsu technique than his current strongest at that point in time (I hope this make sense ^^)
- [Joker Rains](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Joker_Rains) used in the next movie, [Kyuukyoku no Kizuna Gryphon](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Inazuma_Eleven_GO_the_Movie:_The_Ultimate_Bonds_Gryphon) by [Shindou Takuto](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Shindou_Takuto) and [Tsurugi Kyousuke](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Tsurugi_Kyousuke) is similar and isn't used again. Well, that one could be explained if they say they didn't want to use it again.

**Is it just me or are the movies like... completely separate from the anime series? Why are hissatsu techniques exclusively used in movies never used again?** If so, then there's something even stranger:

- [Matsukaze Tenma](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Matsukaze_Tenma) met [Shuu](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/Shuu) the first and only time in the second movie, but knows him when he sees him again in episode 8 of Inazuma Eleven Go: Chrono Stone.
- All those who went to [God Eden](http://inazuma-eleven.wikia.com/wiki/God_Eden) in the movie also know about this place back in the series.

That's about the things I managed to notice, there might be more I didn't. The only thing I can think about is that the first movie alone is like a side/parallel storyline, or an alternative ending to the series, while the second movie is more like an actual event that happened but not much spoken of in the series, which I find really strange.

Comment: Or maybe that's something quite common in anime in general? -Also, thanks JNat!

Comment: I am not sure if it is just me, but I am not exactly sure what's being asked. Do you mean "**Why are** some hissatsu techniques in Inazuma Eleven never used again?"?

Comment: @JNat I added that part and bolded the questions. Sorry it's a bit drowned among the text.

Comment: No problem. I edited your title to include that missing part too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are special just for the movie. They make it that way so the movie is fun to watch with new sorts of hissatsu techniques. If you see better, there are a lot of Avatars in the movie that we didn't saw in the anime episodes too.

Answer (score 0):

Those are separate cases.

- The first movie *The Invasion of the Strongest Army Ogre* is not connected to the main series, since it happened in a different timeline due to the time travel. So in the main anime's timeline, the events in the first movie never happened.
- The second movie *The Ultimate Bonds Gryphon* is canon for GO and occurs between the 2 matches. It is canon, as the next episode features Pegasus arc, and the speech about avatar drawing and talking about batteries and circuits.

Comment: Can you rewrite this in proper English?